# Different hash value of large rsynced file on centos and ubuntu?

Tags: rsync, selinux, hashsum

I rsynced a large file from remote centos to local ubuntu with

```
rsync -avzP user@<remote-ip>:/path/to/file .
```

It reported the transfer went well:

```
sent 30 bytes  received 257,293,476 bytes  1,296,188.95 bytes/sec
total size is 8,217,194,015  speedup is 31.94
```

As far as I know rsync automatically verifies the transfer went well with hash checks after the transfer is completed.

Out of curiosity I computed md5 hashes on centos and ubuntu, and these are different:

```
centos: 0faa300b7b0b81bfe65199da932eb6e2
ubuntu: f3a0fcc59516d4e68fd207bdbb1fc169
```

Both hashes are computed with `md5sum`:

```
centos> md5sum --version
md5sum (GNU coreutils) 8.22

ubuntu> md5sum --version
md5sum (GNU coreutils) 8.25
```

So the verisons are a little different, but can that lead to a different values of the hashes?

**Edit**:

Here are `ls -l` output:

```
centos: -rw-rw-r--.  1 username username 8217194015
ubuntu: -rw-rw-r--   1 username username 8217194015
```

Centos output includes mysterious dot I've never heard about. (could it be related to lvm? lvm is used on that centos)

**Edit 2**:

Checking `md5sum -b` leads to different results as well:

```
centos: 0faa300b7b0b81bfe65199da932eb6e2
ubuntu: 6d799f6981066d82c7f861576b4980e1
```

What hash algorithm does rsync use? [According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#Determining_which_parts_of_a_file_have_changed) rsync uses md5 to check if the chunk is the same:

> The recipient splits its copy of the file into chunks and computes two checksums for each chunk: the MD5 hash, and a weaker but easier to compute 'rolling checksum'. It sends these checksums to the sender. The sender quickly computes the rolling checksum for each chunk in its version of the file; if they differ, it must be sent. If they're the same, the sender uses the more computationally expensive MD5 hash to verify the chunks are the same.

Comment: What did you run `md5sum` on exactly? You copied a directory, but `md5sum` acts on file contents, not on directories.

Comment: @Gilles: I copied a file and run md5sum on that file. Why do you say that I've copied a directory?

Comment: The source of the copy is `.`; that's always a directory. Is the file you checked actually one of the ones you copied? Give us the exact commands (including file and directory names) and their exact output instead of truncating. The problem is highly likely to be because something in what you truncated matters even though you thought it didn't matter.

Comment: @Gilles: when writing a question, I've mistaken the order -- it was `rsync -avzP user@<remote-ip>:/path/to/file .` -- I copied a file from remote machine to the local machine. But is was a file. This is not a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

There's a wrong assumption here:

> As far as I know rsync automatically verifies the transfer went well with hash
>   checks after the transfer is completed.

Rsync uses checksums to determine if a sync is needed. But, Rsync does not reread the created copy, it trust the kernel to report errors. So, the conclusion is simple: the files are not identical. Could be just one bit, could be more. How much mismatch there is, a checksum doesn't tell you.

Answer (score 0):

The dot `.` means, that the file has SELinux context, as every file on CentOS (and no files on Ubuntu), which might confuse `md5sum` in some way. Did you try to run `md5sum` with `b` switch to make sure it will not get mangled by the "to-text" conversions?

Comment: With `md5sum -b` flag centos shows the same checksum as before, but ubuntu shows value different from text mode, and also different from centos value: `ubuntu: 6d799f6981066d82c7f861576b4980e1`.

Comment: An SELinux context has nothing to do with `md5sum -b`. The `md5sum` utility only cares about file contents, not about metadata such as SELinux contests. The `-b` flag only matters on Windows, on Linux it's just ignored.

Comment: @Gilles well, yes, you are obviously right about the `md5sum`, but the question was also about the `.` in the output of `ls`. There is certainly something fishy about the `ubuntu` system, since it prints different hash each time.